# Cloud save issues

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I have PS plus, and I have cloud saves for all of my games.
However, on all of my games, the cloud saves error out with the reason that the save I have is older than the one saved. This is not true.
Is there any way to override this, without manually clicking save for each game?

Comment: This could be an issue with device clocks not being set correctly. Have you checked the time on the console you're trying to save from to make sure it's right?

Comment: It is. The time is the time on my clocks as of now.

Answer (score -1):

Just delete problematic saves stored in PS Plus Cloud and upload them again.

Comment: N o . I have more than 300 saves in the cloud! It would take days!

Comment: Do you get a dialog with question about override existing saves in the PS+ cloud?